# Find v1=? and v2=? for the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, steady-state, nodal-analysis

[image]

This is my solution,but i have a problem with doing a node analysis for node 2 and 3.In my textbook the solution is like this: (2+i1+i1)V1 -2VO -i1V2=0 and(1-i2+i1)V2-i1V1=5

[image]

Comment: Show us your node voltage analysis.  It is cut off at the bottom of your picture.  Also, add the homework tag to your question.

Comment: Also, don't mix j and i for the square root of -1. In EE we use j to avoid confusion with a variable representing a current. Please write your equations using just j.

Comment: @relayman357 First of all the reason it is cut is because it is wrong and in the textbook it is given only the answer and i didn't know how to get there.I am not adding a homework tag,because it is not homework,it is simply for practice. (If it was homework why would i have the answer given??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in your text book is correct:

[image]

The solution would be \$V_1 = 2 - j\$ and \$V_2 = 2+4\cdot j\$.

Comment: Teach a man to fish...or just hand him a free fish.

Comment: Please don't give out homework solutions so quickly. We don't want this to become a homework solving site. We usually try to just give hints....teach the man to fish.

Comment: @relayman357 I don't know if there is any point in understanding something and being good at something if you can't help someone with your knowledge... ‍♀️

Comment: If you give them a homework solution without **guiding them** through the method of solving the problem then you haven't helped anyone. The OP hasn't learned how to solve the next problem they encounter.

Answer (score 0):

> Because you already have the answer I will present my answer using Mathematica. This way you can solve your circuit more generally.

Well, let's solve this mathematically. We have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd0gul.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_9+\text{I}_\text{b}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_{10}+\text{I}_\text{b}\\
\\
\text{I}_{11}=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_{10}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_{11}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, we can use Mathematica to write a code that solves all the unknowns:

```
Va =;
Ib =;
R1 =;
R2 =;
R3 =;
R4 =;
R5 =;
R6 =;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I7, I7 == I3 + I4, I8 == I3 + I4, I8 == I5 + I9, 
   I6 == I9 + Ib, I6 == I10 + Ib, I11 == I5 + I10, I1 == I2 + I11, 
   I1 == (Va - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, 
   I4 == (V1 - V2)/R4, I5 == (V2)/R5, I6 == (V2)/R6}, {I1, I2, I3, I4,
    I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, V1, V2}]]
```

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (we use the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag3$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\text{sL}_1\tag4$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_5=\text{sL}_2\tag6$$

So, for the code we get:

```
Va = LaplaceTransform[u*Cos[\[Omega]1*t], t, s];
Ib = LaplaceTransform[i*Cos[\[Omega]2*t], t, s];
u =;
i =;
\[Omega]1 =;
\[Omega]2 =;
R1 =;
R2 = 1/(s*C1);
R3 = s*L1;
R4 = 1/(s*C2);
R5 = s*L2;
R6 =;
C1 =;
C2 =;
L1 =;
L2 =;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I7, I7 == I3 + I4, I8 == I3 + I4, I8 == I5 + I9, 
   I6 == I9 + Ib, I6 == I10 + Ib, I11 == I5 + I10, I1 == I2 + I11, 
   I1 == (Va - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, 
   I4 == (V1 - V2)/R4, I5 == (V2)/R5, I6 == (V2)/R6}, {I1, I2, I3, I4,
    I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, V1, V2}]]
```

Solving this in your circuit, gives:

```
In[1]:=Va = LaplaceTransform[u*Cos[\[Omega]1*t], t, s];
Ib = LaplaceTransform[i*Cos[\[Omega]2*t], t, s];
u = 5;
i = 5;
\[Omega]1 = 2;
\[Omega]2 = 2;
R1 = 1/2;
R2 = 1/(s*C1);
R3 = s*L1;
R4 = 1/(s*C2);
R5 = s*L2;
R6 = 1;
C1 = 1/2;
C2 = 1;
L1 = 1/2;
L2 = 1/4;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I7, I7 == I3 + I4, I8 == I3 + I4, I8 == I5 + I9, 
   I6 == I9 + Ib, I6 == I10 + Ib, I11 == I5 + I10, I1 == I2 + I11, 
   I1 == (Va - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, 
   I4 == (V1 - V2)/R4, I5 == (V2)/R5, I6 == (V2)/R6}, {I1, I2, I3, I4,
    I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (10 s (16 + s^2 (14 + s + s^2)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + 
      s^2) (4 + s (2 + s))), 
  I2 -> (5 s^3 (14 + s (2 + 3 s)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
      s (2 + s))), 
  I3 -> -((10 (-4 + s) s)/((1 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + s (2 + s)))), 
  I4 -> -((5 (-4 + s) s^3)/((1 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + s (2 + s)))), 
  I5 -> (20 s (12 + s (4 + 7 s)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
      s (2 + s))), 
  I6 -> (5 s^2 (12 + s (4 + 7 s)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
      s (2 + s))), 
  I7 -> -((5 (-4 + s) s (2 + s^2))/((1 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
       s (2 + s)))), 
  I8 -> -((5 (-4 + s) s (2 + s^2))/((1 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
       s (2 + s)))), 
  I9 -> -((5 s (16 + s (16 + 14 s + s^3)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + 
       s^2) (4 + s (2 + s)))), 
  I10 -> -((
    5 s (16 + s (16 + 14 s + s^3)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
       s (2 + s)))), 
  I11 -> -((
    5 (-4 + s) s (2 + s^2))/((1 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + s (2 + s)))), 
  V1 -> (10 s^2 (14 + s (2 + 3 s)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
      s (2 + s))), 
  V2 -> (5 s^2 (12 + s (4 + 7 s)))/((1 + s) (4 + s) (4 + s^2) (4 + 
      s (2 + s)))}}
```